# Highlight selected components VueJS

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm working in Vue file, and what i want is to highlight the active element, what would be the best way to accomplish it?
code

`<li @click = "selectedComponent = 'appBugs1'"><i class="ion-bug"></i>Test 1</li>`

`<li @click = "selectedComponent = 'appBugs2'"><i class="ion-bug"></i>Test 2</li>`

`<li @click = "selectedComponent = 'appBugs3'"><i class="ion-bug"></i>Test 3</li>`

So lets say the first "li" element was selected -> it should give red background to "li", and if another one selected, it must reset the first one and assign the red background to the new selected element.

I tried to search on the web, but there is nothing much about it, it would be easy if you have only 2 options, but my list is much larger. So what would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: Do you want to add a red background when the element's text is selected or when it is clicked?

Comment: for now just a clicked one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this.

```
<li @click = "selectComponent('appBugs1', $event)"><i class="ion-bug"></i>Test 1</li>

<li @click = "selectComponent('appBugs2', $event)"><i class="ion-bug"></i>Test 2</li>

<li @click = "selectComponent('appBugs3', $event)"><i class="ion-bug"></i>Test 3</li>
```

Add the following method:

```
selectComponent: function(component, event){
  if(this.activeLink){
      this.activeLink.classList.remove('highlight');
  }
  this.activeLink = event.target;
  this.activeLink.classList.add('highlight');

  this.selectedComponent = component;
```

};

And the property activeLink. Then add your css styling, for example:

```
.highlight{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: it works only once by some reason. I press the first one, but when i try to go to another one it says (Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined)

Comment: it can start from any of those 3, but once you selected one, u cant switch to another one without refreshing the page

Comment: That probably because of the typo in `activeLink` on my end.